# Solarium Ping request error : Solr HTTP error: Not Found (404)

Tags: php, solr, solarium

I am new to Solr and I am trying to integrate it with my PHP application using Solarium. I tried running the ping query but it is failing and giving  Solr HTTP error: Not Found (404) response.

My PHP code is as follows:

```
    $config = array(
     "endpoint" => array("localhost" => array("host"=>"localhost",
     "port"=>8983, "path"=>"/solr", "core"=>"techproducts",)));

    try{
    $client = new Solarium_Client($config);
    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    if ($client == null) {
        echo 'Client null';
    } else {
        echo 'Client created</br>';
        //v($client);
    }
    // create a ping query
    $ping = $client->createPing();
    if ($ping == null) {
        echo 'ping null';
    } else {
        echo 'ping created</br>';
        //v($ping);
    }
    // execute the ping query
    try{
        $result= $client->ping($ping);
        echo 'Ping query successful';
        echo '<br/><pre>';
        //var_dump($result->getData());
    }catch(Solarium_Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

My Solr server address is :http://localhost:8983/solr/
Core: techproducts

I am getting this output : 
Client created
ping created
Solr HTTP error: Not Found (404)
Can anyone suggest what can be the possible solutions?

Comment: check by adding the "/solr/" in the path...

Comment: Tried it. Not working. What does this "path" actually corresponds to? Can anyone explain?

Comment: This is what he meant `$config = array(
     "endpoint" => array("localhost" => array("host"=>"localhost",
     "port"=>8983, "path"=>"/solr/", "core"=>"techproducts",)));`

Comment: its the contextpath...hows the url get constructed...did you check that...

Comment: @TismonVarghese : you got me correct...

Comment: @TismonVarghese@Abhijit Bashetti I have tried by adding the "/solr/" to path but it is still not working.

Comment: try printing the url and check whats been getting constructed with your code...?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that ping handler is missing into your *solrconfig.xml* file. Please check. You can the below configuration for the same.

```
<!-- ping/healthcheck -->
<requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
    <lst name="invariants">
        <str name="q">solrpingquery</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="echoParams">all</str>
    </lst>
    <!-- An optional feature of the PingRequestHandler is to configure the
         handler with a "healthcheckFile" which can be used to enable/disable
         the PingRequestHandler.
         relative paths are resolved against the data dir
      -->
    <!-- <str name="healthcheckFile">server-enabled.txt</str> -->
</requestHandler>
```

Then you can ping the solr. You can edit the core name in url.
[click Here](http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/admin/ping)

Comment: Ping handler was already configured. Solr ping is working. It is giving correct response. But the solarium is not able to get a response from solr server.